# Magento 2.3 Contact form in modal popup not showing Google recaptcha

Tags: magento2, recaptcha

I have written a module that loads the default contact form in to a default Magento modal window (I load the form in to the footer first):

/app/code/Sulman/PopupContactForm/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Sulman_PopupContactForm::css/contact-popup.css" />
    </head>
    <referenceContainer name="footer">
        <block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml">
            <container name="form.additional.info" label="Form Additional Info"/>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="popup-button" template="Sulman_PopupContactForm::popup-button.phtml"></block>
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

/app/code/Sulman/PopupContactForm/view/frontend/templates/popup-button.phtml

```
<div class="contact-popup-button" style="">
    <a href="#" id="open-contact-popup">Contact Us</a>
</div>
<script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function(
            $,
            modal
        ) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Close'),
                    class: '',
                    click: function () {
                        this.closeModal();
                    }
                }]
            };

            var popup = modal(options, $('#contact-form'));
            $( "#open-contact-popup" ).click(function() {
               $('#contact-form').modal('openModal');
            });

        }
    );
</script>
```

This is working correctly and loads the contact form in the popup just fine.

But now I want to add the default Magento Google recaptcha to the contact form. I have enabled it and it is showing correctly on the contact form (/contact) but it does not show on the contact popup. Any ideas?

I can see the code to load the recaptcha in the source of the main contact page:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "#msp-recaptcha-container": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {"components":{"msp-recaptcha":{"component":"MSP_ReCaptcha\/js\/reCaptcha","zone":"contact","settings":{"siteKey":"xxx","size":"normal","badge":null,"theme":"light","lang":null,"enabled":{"login":true,"create":true,"forgot":true,"contact":true}}}}}    }
}
</script>
```

But it is not appearing on the popup source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. I just needed to add the MSP block to the `form.additional.info` container in my modules default.xml:

```
    <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
        <block class="MSP\ReCaptcha\Block\Frontend\ReCaptcha" name="msp-recaptcha" after="-"
               template="MSP_ReCaptcha::msp_recaptcha.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="msp-recaptcha" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">MSP_ReCaptcha/js/reCaptcha</item>
                            <item name="zone" xsi:type="string">contact</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

So my final default.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Sulman_PopupContactForm::css/contact-popup.css" />
    </head>
    <referenceContainer name="footer">
        <block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml">
            <container name="form.additional.info" label="Form Additional Info"/>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="popup-button" template="Sulman_PopupContactForm::popup-button.phtml"></block>
    </referenceContainer>

    <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
        <block class="MSP\ReCaptcha\Block\Frontend\ReCaptcha" name="msp-recaptcha" after="-"
               template="MSP_ReCaptcha::msp_recaptcha.phtml">

            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="msp-recaptcha" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">MSP_ReCaptcha/js/reCaptcha</item>
                            <item name="zone" xsi:type="string">contact</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

Google recaptcha now works on the popup correctly.